# SQL inner join with top to JPPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT b.NAME, b.ID, hc1.CATCH_DATE, hc1.id
FROM BIRD b
         INNER JOIN HEALTH_CHECK hc1 ON hc1.BIRD_ID = b.ID
         INNER JOIN
     (
         SELECT BIRD_ID, MAX(CATCH_DATE) AS MAX_DATE
         FROM HEALTH_CHECK
         GROUP BY BIRD_ID
     ) hc2
     ON hc2.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID AND
        hc2.MAX_DATE = hc1.CATCH_DATE
WHERE b.ID=1;
```

This returns a bird record with only the newest HealthCheck.

I would like to convert this to JPQL but can't find how to do this with the nested INNER JOIN.

Comment: There is no way to write this JPQL. Why don't you stay with SQL?

Comment: @SimonMartinelliwhen mapping the results JPQL offeres features not available with native SQL I think.

Comment: What should be the result of the query? Entity? If yes this is no problem

Comment: Its some fields from one entity (BIrd) and a single field from HealthCheck.

Answer (score 0):

You must use SQL because JPQL is not able to create such a query.

As a result, you must use a DTO. The result of the query can be transformed to DTOs using Hibernate Transformer

For example:

```
List<PersonSummaryDTO> dtos = session.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT p.id as \"id\", p.name as \"name\" " +
    "FROM Person p")
.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( PersonSummaryDTO.class ) )
.list();
```

Please find all information in the Hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-dto-query